# How do i add a scoring system to my rock paper and scissors game?

Tags: c#

I'm just a beginner in c# so please correct my mistakes and don't hesitate to give criticism. What I have here is a rock paper scissor program.

- I want to create a scoring system wherein if player wins then the score will increment by 1 and if it's a draw then it will not increment.
- I want the game to have at least five rounds.

  using System;

  class RockpaperScissors {
  static void Main() {

  ```
   string player;

   string computer;

   bool restart = true;

   int randomNum;

   Random random = new Random();

   string response;

      while (restart){
          player = "";
          computer = "";
          randomNum = 0;
          while (player != "ROCK" && player != "PAPER" && player != "SCISSORS"){
              Console.WriteLine("ROCK, PAPER or SCISSORS?");
              player = Console.ReadLine();
              player = player.ToUpper();

              randomNum = random.Next(1,3 + 1);
               if (randomNum == 1){
                   computer = "ROCK";
               }
               else if(randomNum == 2){
                   computer = "PAPER";
               }
               else if (randomNum == 3){
                   computer = "SCISSORS";
               }



              switch (player){

                  case "ROCK" : // ROCK
                    if (computer == "ROCK"){
                        Console.WriteLine("It is a DRAW!");
                        Console.WriteLine("player: " + player);
                        Console.WriteLine("computer: " + computer);
                        Console.WriteLine("would you like to play again? (Y,N)");
                        response = Console.ReadLine();
                        response = response.ToUpper();

                        // restart ...
                        if (response == "Y"){
                            restart = true;
                        }
                        else {
                            restart = false;
                        }
                        // restart ...
                    }

                    else if (computer == "PAPER"){
                         Console.WriteLine("player wins!");
                        Console.WriteLine("player: " + player);
                        Console.WriteLine("computer: " + computer);
                        Console.WriteLine("would you like to play again? (Y,N)");
                        response = Console.ReadLine();
                        response = response.ToUpper();


                         // restart ...
                        if (response == "Y"){
                            restart = true;
                        }
                        else {
                            restart = false;
                        }
                        // restart ...
                    }
                        else if (computer == "ROCK"){
                            Console.WriteLine("computer wins!");
                        Console.WriteLine("player: " + player);
                        Console.WriteLine("computer: " + computer);
                        Console.WriteLine("would you like to play again? (Y,N)");
                        response = Console.ReadLine();
                        response = response.ToUpper();


                         // restart ...
                        if (response == "Y"){
                            restart = true;
                        }
                        else {
                            restart = false;
                        }
                        // restart ...

                        }


                    break;
                    // PAPER ...
                  case "PAPER" :
                   if (computer == "ROCK"){
                        Console.WriteLine("Player wins!");
                        Console.WriteLine("player: " + player);
                        Console.WriteLine("computer: " + computer);
                        Console.WriteLine("would you like to play again? (Y,N)");
                        response = Console.ReadLine();
                        response = response.ToUpper();

                        // restart ...
                        if (response == "Y"){
                            restart = true;
                        }
                        else {
                            restart = false;
                        }
                        // restart ...
                    }

                    else if (computer == "PAPER"){
                         Console.WriteLine("Its a draw!");
                        Console.WriteLine("player: " + player);
                        Console.WriteLine("computer: " + computer);
                        Console.WriteLine("would you like to play again? (Y,N)");
                        response = Console.ReadLine();
                        response = response.ToUpper();


                         // restart ...
                        if (response == "Y"){
                            restart = true;
                        }
                        else {
                            restart = false;
                        }
                        // restart ...
                    }
                        else if (computer == "ROCK"){
                            Console.WriteLine("computer wins!");
                        Console.WriteLine("player: " + player);
                        Console.WriteLine("computer: " + computer);
                        Console.WriteLine("would you like to play again? (Y,N)");
                        response = Console.ReadLine();
                        response = response.ToUpper();


                         // restart ...
                        if (response == "Y"){
                            restart = true;
                        }
                        else {
                            restart = false;
                        }
                        // restart ...
                        }
                        break;
                        // SCISSORS
                        case "SCISSORS":
                        if (computer == "ROCK"){
                        Console.WriteLine("Computer wins");
                        Console.WriteLine("player: " + player);
                        Console.WriteLine("computer: " + computer);
                        Console.WriteLine("would you like to play again? (Y,N)");
                        response = Console.ReadLine();
                        response = response.ToUpper();

                        // restart ...
                        if (response == "Y"){
                            restart = true;
                        }
                        else {
                            restart = false;
                        }
                        // restart ...
                    }

                    else if (computer == "PAPER"){
                         Console.WriteLine("player wins!");
                        Console.WriteLine("player: " + player);
                        Console.WriteLine("computer: " + computer);
                        Console.WriteLine("would you like to play again? (Y,N)");
                        response = Console.ReadLine();
                        response = response.ToUpper();


                         // restart ...
                        if (response == "Y"){
                            restart = true;
                        }
                        else {
                            restart = false;
                        }
                        // restart ...
                    }
                        else if (computer == "ROCK"){
                            Console.WriteLine("its a draw!!");
                        Console.WriteLine("player: " + player);
                        Console.WriteLine("computer: " + computer);
                        Console.WriteLine("would you like to play again? (Y,N)");
                        response = Console.ReadLine();
                        response = response.ToUpper();


                         // restart ...
                        if (response == "Y"){
                            restart = true;
                        }
                        else {
                            restart = false;
                        }
                        // restart ...
                        }
                        break;
          }
              }

          }

      }  
  }
  ```

Comment: Sorry if I missed something… but, I do not see anywhere in your code that attempts to keep track of the “scoring” you describe. Nor the five (5) rounds aspect of the game. What have you tried in reference to keeping track of the players score? And ending the game after five rounds?

Comment: Yup ... Unfortunately I don't know how to keep track of the scores and stuff and I just can't find a way on how to stop the game after five rounds. I tried doing it using for loops , I just don't know how to execute it. That's why I'm asking for help....

Comment: I understand. Well, think about it… you already HAVE a loop the goes on forever. Maybe use it to only loop 5 times? As a hint, I highly recommend you “break” your code up into small pieces. In other words, you have ONE (1) method (main) that does everything. Have you considered making a method, that gets the random computer choice? Then another method, that gets the users choice. Then possibly another method that checks the results of the player and computer choices and returns a result.

Comment: Example, looking at your current code, I am confident even you can see the “duplicate” code. The only difference in each code “duplication” are the `string` choices. This should be a red flag to you that you should make a separate method and call it each time as opposed to “duplicating” the code. Try something and if you get stuck, post it here. I am confident you can figure it out if you give it a try.